# Magento & soap2: how to get custom attribute using catalogCategoryInfo function?

Tags: magento, soap

Function *catalogCategoryInfo* returns fixed size count of attribute. Not all attributes are seeing. How to get custom category attribute?

I added to wsdl.xml (catalog):

```
<complexType name="catalogCategoryInfo">
    <all>
         <element name="new_attribue" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />                      
    </all>
</complexType>
```

and for wsi.xml (catalog):

```
 <xsd:complexType name="catalogCategoryInfo">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="new_attribue" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" />
      </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! I've got it.

The problem was in soap cache.
The function _instantiateServer in Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap class has 
`ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0')`
option which didn't work.

The cache option of soap in php.ini has been turned on. I just turned it off.

```
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=0
```

Now it works perfect!